Mermaid gantt, how to create a milestone with multiline title
A MWE for mermaid gantt is as the following
gantt
dateFormat YY-MM-DD
        section Section
            Milestone A (4/15) : milestone, , 4/15/2024, 0D
            Milestone B (9/19) : milestone, , 9/19/2025, 0D

Yield the following

I now want to split the milestone title to multiple lines, like the following

Tried <br>, \n and <tspan>, both not taking effect.
Any suggestion on how to achieve this?
